# The idea of the proof of a theorem.

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Could anyone explain the contradiction that he will use to prove the theorem?

Especially when he said that:" the idea now is to construct a family of trigonometric functions ${p_{k}}$ that peaks at 0, and so that $$\int p_{k}( \theta) f(\theta) d\theta \rightarrow \infty as\ k\ \rightarrow \infty.$$
This will be our contradiction, since those integrals tends to zero by assumption."

I do not see what is the assumption that makes them tends to zero and why the integral above tends to $\infty.$

Thanks.
they are attached in the following photos.

[image: the theorem]
[image: the proof part 1]
[image: the proof part 2]

Comment: The integrals $\int p_k(\theta) f(\theta) \ d\theta$ are all **equal** to zero (not merely "tend to zero"), because each $p_k$ is a trigonometric polynomial, and the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are zero by hypothesis.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670464/difficulty-in-understanding-a-part-in-a-proof-from-stein-and-shakarchi-fourier-a) might be useful!

Comment: @VikrantDesai .... thank u sooo much :))

Comment: Marking your question as a duplicate okay. ;) So that the answer will be found under a single hood. :)

Comment: @Bungo Thank u sooo much.

Comment: @Bungo ..... and why $$\int p_{k}( \theta) f(\theta) d\theta \rightarrow \infty as\ k\ \rightarrow \infty.$$

Comment: @Bungo I mean why when { $p_{k}$} peaks at 0, when the previous integral tend to $\infty$ as k tend to $\infty$