# Find the equation of a circle.....

Tags: circles

Find the equation of a circle with radius 4 units, whose Centre lies on the line $4x+13y=32$ and which touches the line $4x+3y+28=0$.
[image]

I could only make a figure with the help of the question. can anyone help me to complete this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$13y=4(8-x)$$

If $8-x=13h\iff x=8-13h\iff y=4h$

So WLOG, the coordinate of the center can be written as $(8-13h,4h)$

Now the distance of the center from the tangent $=$ radius

$$\implies4=\dfrac{|4(8-13h)+3(4h)+28|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}$$

Can you complete the square & take the problem home from here?

Comment: Why did you use 'h'?

Comment: @user335710, $$h$$ is a parameter. Btw, have you understood the method?

Comment: Nice & short solution, looks good when solved and plotted (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ISDoC.png). Especially emphasized the fact that there are two solutions.

Comment: @Lab, not clearly...

Comment: @user335710, Please pinpoint your confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by WLOG?

Comment: @user335710, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/wlog-means-losing-generality   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129137/use-of-without-loss-of-generality

Comment: And here the parameter means, A constant in the equation of a curve that canbe varied to yield a family of similar curves; is it it true?

Comment: Also, completing the square and solving the equation doesn't give answer in terms of $x$ and $y$, why is it so?

Comment: @user335710, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation#Examples_in_two_dimensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41301/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-user335710).

Comment: You have used 'h' in place of 'y'?

Comment: @user335710, For the ease of calculation. But you  are free to not do so

Answer (score 0):

Lab's solution is clever.  It may be helpful to explain a bit more his thinking.

The equation $4x+13y=32$ is a line, as you already see, and it has infinitely many points that satisfy it.

Since there are two variables and one equation, there is $2-1=1$ free parameter (which is called $h$ in Lab's solution).  Expressing the line in terms of this free parameter is a matter of getting the two variables on opposite sides, and then equating them to the free parameter.

The way it's done in Lab's solution may seem a bit like magic but he sees where he wants to go, and doesn't want to deal with fractions until he has to.

First the equation is rearranged to $13y = 32 - 4x = 4(8-x)$.  He sees the opportunity to set $8-x = 13h$ (which he can do at this point).  Isolating $x$ gives $x = 8 - 13h$.  Upon substituting it there, he has $13y = 4 \cdot 13h$, which gives $y=4h$.

Why do all of this?  Because now the line is completely described with one variable, $h$, and the values of $x,y$ can be calculated from $h$.  Now it's just a matter of applying the distance formula for a distance $d$ from a point $(x_0, y_0)$ to the line $ax+by+c=0$:

$$d = \frac{|ax_0 + by_0 + c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Here, $(x_0, y_0)$ is a point on your parameterized line, which is $(8-13h, 4h)$.

Hope this helps!